# Canada Express entry - CRS - Skill Transferability - Education

Tags: canada

I received 0 points for CRS - Skill Transferability - Education.

Below are my details:

1. 4 year Bachelor's degree in Electrical Engineering
2. 1+ year Canadian work experience
3. CELPIP - Reading: 11 ; Writing: 10 ; Listening: 11 ; Speaking: 7

I'm waiting for my Educational Credential Assessment (ECA) from WES as well. So, my Express Entry profile is not yet updated with ECA.

Can someone please help check if a score of 0 normal? What can I do to improve it?

Comment: From what I have heard from others, that's correct until the ECA is added to your profile.

Answer (score 2):

The Express Entry calculator only counts official ECAs, so it will show as zero points until you get your official results back. Until then, it will show you as ineligible.

You can [calculate your score on your own](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp) using the criteria on the CIC website.